# Suppressing GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor warnings

Tags: java, spring, grails

I see a bunch of warnings that start with:

> springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor Invalid
>   JavaBean property '...' being accessed!

Is there a way to suppress these, I don't see any errors or issues with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation above the method to suppress the warning, but that should be a last resort.